# Date Range Filter Standard

Tags: dates, calendar, datepicker

Has anyone encountered Date Range Filtering Standards in any business areas?

What is the best practice in Date Range Filtering, V1 or V2?
What could be some better options than this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There can be some more approaches apart from the ones shown in the question. For e.g. the user should be shown a calendar indicator if they can pick from a calendar next to the input box. A detailed answer can be found here on UX.StackExchange: [Better way for users to select a date range](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1740/better-way-for-users-to-select-a-date-range?rq=1)

Material Design Guidelines: https://material.io/components/date-pickers#desktop-pickers
[image]

Google Bookings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the audience and device (mobile/ desktop). From an Accessibility perspective V1 is better because it includes labels.

Comment: could you explain how the audience affects picking a particular filter?